# How to add a line feed after each digit that came before a letter

Tags: c#, string, insert, linefeed

i have a string like that:

```
String s ="6,44 6,35    +0,63asd    4,27fgh 4,14  45,6 +777,4cvbvc";
```

I want to insert a line feed into those points between every digit and letter like: **+0,63(here must be a line break)asd**. I wrote the code below but it gave length changed error. Maybe it may occur either because of my program's features or c#'s feature. But i need to stay stick to the features. So can you recommend me a solution in those limits? The code below could not solve it and i could not find any other way.

```
int k = s.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            if (char.IsDigit(s[i - 1]) && char.IsLetter(s[i]))
                s = s.Insert(i, Strings.Chr(10).ToString());
```

Thank you for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Explore RegEx es mate: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the cycle from 1 or you will get an exception because when `i=0` `s[i-1]` becomes `s[-1]`.
Now your program should work but i would suggest you to use a stringbuilder because `string.Insert` creates a new string instance everytime you call it making your program very slow if the input string is long.
Also if you are in a Windows environment a line break is represented by "\r\n" wich is Environment.NewLine in c#.
So your code should be something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(s);
int offset=0;
for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(s[i - 1]) && char.IsLetter(s[i]))
    {
        builder.Insert(i+offset, Environment.NewLine);
        //every time you add a line break you need to increment the offset
        offset+=Environment.NewLine.Length;
    }
}
s=builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution hase one mistake - loop index range, you should start with 1, because you have expression (i-1)
here is solution
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMvpqj

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
    String myString="";
    int k = s.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                if (char.IsDigit(s[i - 1]) && char.IsLetter(s[i]))
                    myString = myString + Strings.Chr(10).ToString() + s.Substring(i,k-i);
s=myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
int k = s.Length;
int i= 1;
while (i < s.Length)
{
    if ((char.IsDigit(s[i - 1]) && char.IsLetter(s[i])) ||
        (char.IsLetter(s[i-1]) && char.IsDigit(s[i])))
    {
        s = s.Insert(i, ((char)10).ToString());
        i++;
    }
    i++;
}
```